# How to add d3.js-only slider to the SVG composition

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have pure d3.js slider:

http://thematicmapping.org/playground/d3/d3.slider/

https://github.com/turban/d3.slider

How can I add it to my SVG composition?

Given I want to add slider2 to my composition, I tried something like:

```
 <svg>
    <g id='something'>
         <div id='slider2'></div>
    </g>
 </svg>
```

That slider gets rendered outside the SVG composition

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with your SVG composition?

Comment: Those sliders are not constructed out of SVG elements but HTML.  You could only include them in an SVG tag using `foreignObject` but there's no IE support.  You'd have better luck with an actual [SVG implementation](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972)

Comment: Mark you can write this response as an answer to my problem - I will accept it